# Automount disk on boot

Tags: mount, disk, fstab, automount

I've used XBMC live in the past and have been happy with manually editing /etc/fstab to configure disks to automatically mount.

Now I am running Ubuntu 12.10. Within "disks" i have the mount options on the drives set to "Automatic Mount Options: On" but the disks are'nt mounted until I access them.

The disks aren't listed in /etc/fstab- I could add them by hand, but I am expecting the GUI to take care of it?

Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get them automounting using AriOS Automount. I'll wait to see if anyone can explain why ubuntu isn't doing what I expect it to do naturally before accepting my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 'Automatic Mount Options: On'! That just sets it to use the default options for automounting, which for me at least apparently means that the drive *isn't* automounted. This is perhaps a tad confusing, as you might expect the greyed out settings below to show the  default settings, but they don't.

Instead, you should set 'Automatic Mount Options' to 'Off' and make sure the 'Mount at startup' and 'Show in user interface' checkboxes are selected manually. You might also want to change the 'Mount Point' to something more readable and useful that /mnt/[UUID] or whatever it defaults to.

I know this question is pretty old, but it still comes up on searches and is still relevant to new versions, so I thought it useful to answer properly. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

the answer u r expecting might be pySDM, its very useful - 
In terminal type -

```
sudo apt-get install pysdm
```

and then please follow the link -

[Mount Partitions & External Devices at boot time](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/11/mount-partitions-external-devices-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-with-pysdm/)

P.S - I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Hope this helps.

Comment: so am I misunderstanding what the "automatic mount options" should do?

Comment: try it - open the automatic mount option interface and turn it off. Then tick on "MOUNT AT STARTUP". write in the options textbox right below the "icon name"- `,umask=027,owner`. Mention the mount point if it is not already there as `/media/<anything>`.

Comment: an error occurred while mounting /mnt/xxx press s to skip mounting or m for manual recovery